# Implementing Caches in C

Tags: c, caching, struct

I am confused and not sure if what i am doing is correct...

```
typedef struct Node {
   size_t tag;                
   struct Node *next;   
   int valid;
} Node;

typedef struct caches {
   struct Node *tag; 
   int hits;
   int misses;
   int Coldmisses;
} caches;
```

These are my structs.....

I created a method...

```
caches* L1Cache() {
    caches *l1 = malloc(numberofsets1*sizeof(caches));
    if (numberofsets1 != 1) {
        numberofsets1 = L1Size/(blocksize*L1assoc);
    }
    l1->hits = 0;
    l1->misses = 0;
    l1->tag->valid = 0;
    l1->Coldmisses = 0;
    return l1;
}
```

in my main I called it like `caches* L1 = L1Cache()`;
then can i use the L1 something like this????
Also I am getting SEGEMENTATION FAULT "l1->tag->valid = 0;" here IDK WHY?? Help please

```
if (L1[indexoffset].tag->valid = 0) {
    L1[indexoffset].tag->tag = tag;
    L1[indexoffset].tag->valid = 1;
}
```

Comment: Did you really mean `= 0` instead of `== 0` on the last `if`?

Comment: yeah i meant ==0... and another question I am getting segmentation fault when i do "l1->tag->valid = 0;" I am not sure why

Comment: It is because `tag` in `l1->tag->valid` access is uninitialized. ?

Comment: Can i do `l1->tag=NULL;` and then `l1->tag->valid`

Comment: No, as @Uchia pointed out, you can not access `tag->valid` if you do not write `l1->tag=malloc(sizeof(Node))` somewhere. A good practice would be to initialize `l1->tag=NULL` then run some code then test `if(l1->tag!=NULL){l1->tag->valid=1}` Try this !

Comment: What if I add `l1->tag=malloc(sizeof(Node));` in `caches* L1Cache()` right after `l1->misses = 0;`

Comment: @francis What if I add l1->tag=malloc(sizeof(Node)); in caches* L1Cache() right after l1->misses = 0; – user3100209

Comment: It should work. Do not forget to free it at the end or if you change the pointer ( `l1->tag=othernode`).

Answer (score 0):

> What if I add `l1->tag=malloc(sizeof(Node));` in `caches* L1Cache()`
>   right after `l1->misses = 0;` – user3100209

It should work. Do not forget to free it at the end or if you change the pointer ( `l1->tag=othernode`). – francis